# Blue Prism Excel export without headers

Tags: excel, automation, blueprism, rpa

I'm searching for a solution for this:
I have an excel file with headers that contain "." this is a problem for Blue Prism because it can't work with it to set a value.

For example: I have ExportCollection with column A, B. and C

if I use the calculation for this collection to parse it to another collection with column A and B, I would do this:

[ExportCollection.A] store in [NewCollection.A]
[ExportCollection.B.] store in [NewCollection.B]

now the last one will give me an error.

My solution was, maybe I can extract the data into my ExportCollection without headers but I don't know how to do this.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What Action in Excel VBO are you using? Surely GetWorksheetAsCollectionOffset Action in Excel VBO can be of use - because it has a 'Use Header' flag

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an object from the Collection Manipulation Utility VBO that has an action which removes dots from headers , its called "Remove dots from headers". Its also useful when headers came with dots "." from the excel file. Therefore, you can work with the values once removed